# Dart: DateTime.parse() not including microseconds

Tags: dart

See the following code:

```
void main() 
{
  String test = '2017-10-11T12:03:46.351363-04:00';
  DateTime testDate = DateTime.parse(test);
  print(testDate.microsecond);
  print(testDate.toString());
}
```

When running this code I lose the microseconds in the string that I parse. Why is this and is there anyway to solve this?

The Dart docs say that the parse method supports microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

`'2017-10-11T12:03:46.351363-04:00'` is not a format Dart's `DateTime` can handle.

`DateTime` only supports `Z` for GMT or no `Z` for local time.

Just print the value from a created `DateTime` to see what format it can parse.

```
print(DateTime.now());
print(DateTime.now().toUtc())
```

`DateTime` has also 2 constructors `fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch` and `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` to create an instance from an integer value.

Comment: Fair enough. Although, if you try to parse this: '2012-02-27 13:27:00.123456z' then you also lose the microseconds. And this is an accepted format. In fact this one of the example accepted formats taken from the Dart docs:

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Comment: It even accepts `2002-02-27T14:00:00-0500`, but without `:` in the timezone offset. I don't know why it drops microseconds, because it actually can handle microseconds.

Comment: DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2017, 9, 7, 17, 30, 10, 351, 363); print(dateTime); Even that doesn't keep the microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue here
https://github.com/dart-lang/co19/issues/17

As the test show it only 6 decimal places
https://github.com/dart-lang/co19/commit/8465825f60c9580d82ae01ffc040f3b589aaf667#diff-02c526d1dcb5aa2dcdab3500c14ede87R40

You can parse format `2018-12-11T12:00:32.304272Z`

but cannot parse `2018-12-11T12:00:32.304272001Z`

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue for dart-lang/sdk.
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44876

> The web Date object doesn't support microseconds. It's implemented
> using the JavaScript Date object which only supports millisecond
> precision. So, working as well as possible.